# java.io.NotSerializableException: Etudiant

Tags: java, rmi

I created a simple RMI application where I have :

```
public interface IAbsence extends Remote {
    void inscrire(Etudiant e) throws RemoteException;
}

public class Absence extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IAbsence{
    protected Absence() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        listEtudiants = new ArrayList<Etudiant>();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<Etudiant> listEtudiants;

    public void inscrire(Etudiant e) throws RemoteException {
        listEtudiants.add(e);

    }
}
```

and for the server I have the following :

```
public class Serveur {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        Absence absence = new Absence();


             try {
                 Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(52356);
                    registry.bind("Absence_RMI", absence);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            System.out.println("server ON");

    }

}
```

and for the client I have this :

```
public class ClientEtudiant {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",52356);
            IAbsence absence_rmi = (IAbsence)registry.lookup("Absence_RMI");

            ///.... some code
            absence_rmi.inscrire(new Etudiant(nom, prenom, cne));
            System.out.println("L'étudiant a été inscrit");
        } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException  e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        }
}
```

When I run the server it works without problems, but when I run the client I get an error on the line `absence_rmi.inscrire...` which says :

> java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested
>   exception is:     java.io.NotSerializableException: Etudiant

Comment: Have that class implement the Serializable interface.

Comment: RMI needs Serializable to turn your Java object into a String to send over the wire from the client to the server.

Comment: Really. The exception message could hardly be clearer.

Comment: Not only that, but you posted 3 snippets of code, and none is showing the only class mentioned in the error message: Etudiant. **Read** the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are trying to send over your custom object, you must implement [**Interface Serializable**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) .

Clearly, from [**NotSerializableException Docs**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) you get this exception, when your class has to implement this interface, and you didn't.

Secondly, [**MarshallException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/MarshalException.html) has a clear explanation in the Docs with possible reasons. Make sure that your RMI works with primitive types at least.

Comment: There's no 'probably' about it. He didn't. Similarly there is no 'try to' about it either.